# avoid making a play app for a core module

Tags: scala, playframework

have a modularized application

```
my-core
my-module1
my-module2
```

`my-core` is a regular `sbt` project while other modules are `play` apps. Now as much as I wanted to avoid making `my-core` a play app (for no specific reason but because `my-core` never serves any endpoints but only house core code which is used by all others like `my-module1`, `my-module2` etc). now situation is that other play modules `my-module1` and `my-module2` are depending on `play` to do things like

```
lazy val db: Database = {
if (play.api.Play.isTest(play.api.Play.current)) dosmething
else if (play.api.Play.isDev(play.api.Play.current)) dosomething else
else dosomething else

}
```

Above code should not be repeated in all modules but live in core. That brings up a situation to make `my-core` a play application. I am stating the obvious here but do you see any way to still keep `my-core` simple sbt project and not play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to make it a play app but you will need to depend on play libraries. According to the code sample, my-core will need to depend on both

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play" % "2.3.0" 

libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-jdbc" % "2.3.0"
```

(remember to change the version to match the actual play version)

Depending on the play library instead of adding the play plugin avoids adding the routes compiler, the templates compiler, the custom source directories and all to your build.

Comment: realizing that I don't see play-core in http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/play/ you know where `play-core` is ?

Comment: My bad, you want http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/play/play_2.10/2.3.0/

Comment: oh.. you're saying I need entire play as dependency? : http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/play/play_2.11/2.3.4/

Comment: well, play.api.db.Database is in play-jdbc but for now play.api.Play is in the main jar. you can exclude unnecessary dependenciesif needed